# Android Studio displays two drawable with the same name

Tags: android, android-studio, launcher-icon

Androis Studio displays two drawable of the same name and one of them contains different picture, than another.

[image]

The one tagged with `v24` contains incorrect picture (default Android icon) and another one contains correct picture, which I have generated with `Image Asset Studio`.

How to wipe out incorrect picture or make it correct?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to delete it but you can do it with right click and then delete. What is wrong with the picture?

Comment: If I delete it, it says it is used in `ic_launcer.xml` and in `ic_launcher_round.xml`, while inside these files it is written `<foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>`, i.e. w/o v24.

Answer (score 0):

this is API level. Android 7.0 (API level 24) meaning minSdkVersion 24 and you can see your minSdkVersion in gradle file.

You can also delete ic_launcher_foreground.xml (v24)